# bash: syntax error near unexpected token '<'

Tags: command-line, bash, chromebook, crouton

I am using [this](https://www.codedonut.com/chromebook/install-crouton-chromebook/) guide to install Ubuntu on my Chromebook via crouton. 
It mentions a part about updating drivers and tells me to enter

```
<em><code>sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

but this returns:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token '<'
```

I assume this is because the terminal doesn't recognize '<'. If this is the case how should I make this work?

I just typed what was in the guide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command should be:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

If you will review the code snippet in that guide, you will see that it start with: `<em><code>` and ends with: `</code></em>` those headers aren't part of the actual commands which should be executed in Linux

Comment: I'm also having trouble with the next commands that include URLs. I hit enter and nothing happened, it just started a new line with (trusty)tony@localhost:~$

Answer (score 23):

`<em>` and `<code>` are HTML tags controlling how text is displayed in the site. They leaked into the commands for some reason, and the page is full of such formatting errors:

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -u -n <strong>chrootname</strong>
```

The `<strong>` tags shouldn't be there.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade</code></em>
```

Again, `<code>` and `<em>` tags shouldn't be present. And the `<b>` tag here:

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r <b>ubuntuversion</b> -t keyboard -u
```

`&amp;` instead of `&` here:

```
sudo apt-get update &amp;&amp; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And probably other such mistakes. Consider looking for another guide or asking the author to fix these errors.

Comment: "They leaked into the commands for some reason" -
 that _might_ have something to do with the fact that the blogger blindly ripped off that part from [another website](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-on.html).

Comment: @undercat in that case, that's the "another guide" OP needs. :)